# What should be used as an event parameter with FBSDKAppEventParameterNameOrderID key in Facebook Analytics SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-analytics

FBSDKAppEventParameterNameOrderID is name for event parameter for both FBSDKAppEventNameSubscribe and FBSDKAppEventNameStartTrial events. Official documentation contains the following description for it.

```
/** Parameter key used to specify the unique ID for all events within a subscription
  * in an FBSDKAppEventNameSubscribe or FBSDKAppEventNameStartTrial event. */
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const FBSDKAppEventParameterNameOrderID;
```

As for me, there are two meaningful things, which may be put in the subscription events:

1. **Original Transaction Identifier**, which can be used by Facebook Analytics' backend to collapse all reported subscription renewals into a single real subscription.
2. **Transaction Identifier**, which is unique for each new subscription and all its renewals. That is what Facebook Analytics SDK is looking for according to documentation, but less meaningful from a marketing point of view.

So what is the right value for FBSDKAppEventParameterNameOrderID parameter in FBSDKAppEventNameSubscribe/FBSDKAppEventNameStartTrial events?